# Why is the array my fucntion is returing not defined outside of my function?

Tags: python, numpy

I am working on an assignment that requires I graph an array from one part of the assignment in another part. I cannot get the averages_table array to be defined outside of my function, so I cannot pass it through another. I am pretty new to coding so there may be some other sub-optimal parts of my code, but for the purposes of this assignment I just need my array to be accessible in other parts of my code. I have pasted what I have worked on so far below. Thank you to anyone that takes a look!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

```
def Section1_5_airportAverages():
    print('5. File aircrafts.csv contains monthly aircraft arrival and departure data recorded at an airport\n'
          'from 2010 to 2015. Open the aircrafts.csv file using any text editor (or using any spreadsheet\n'
          'application) to see the content - use Notepad, TextEdit, or similar text editor to see comma separated\n'
          'values and format. Your task is to write a program to analyze the data using Numpy arrays and output\n'
          'average number of arrivals and departures in each year – in the following format.\n')
    airports = np.genfromtxt('aircrafts.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header=1, dtype=str)
    year = 2010
    count = 0
    total_arrivals_per_year = 0
    total_departures_per_year = 0
    averages_table = np.empty((0),str)
    print('Year Arrivals Departures')  # Header for table
    while True:
        for i, value in enumerate(airports):  # Iterates through airports and assigns an index to each element.
            if count < 11 and year <= 2015:
                count += 1
                total_arrivals_per_year += airports[i][1].astype(int)
                total_departures_per_year += airports[i][2].astype(int)
            elif count == 11 and year < 2015:  # Allows holding variable to be reset, and increments year.
                count += 1
                total_arrivals_per_year += airports[i][1].astype(int)
                average_arrivals_per_year = total_arrivals_per_year/count
                total_departures_per_year += airports[i][2].astype(int)
                average_departures_per_year = total_departures_per_year / count
                print(year, average_arrivals_per_year.round(2), average_departures_per_year.round(2))
                count = 0
                year += 1
                total_arrivals_per_year = 0
                total_departures_per_year = 0
                averages_table = np.append(averages_table,[year, average_arrivals_per_year, average_departures_per_year])
            elif count == 11 and year == 2015: # Ends the function after year 2015 is complete.
                count += 1
                total_arrivals_per_year += airports[i][1].astype(int)
                average_arrivals_per_year = total_arrivals_per_year / count
                total_departures_per_year += airports[i][2].astype(int)
                average_departures_per_year = total_departures_per_year / count
                print(year, average_arrivals_per_year.round(2), average_departures_per_year.round(2))
                averages_table = np.append(averages_table,
                                           [year, average_arrivals_per_year,  average_departures_per_year]).reshape((6,3)).astype(float).round(2)
                return averages_table
```

Comment: you need to outdent your return statement to be at the same level as you while statement

Comment: @itprorh66j No, I don't think so. That `return` is OP's way to break the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to explain as below, there might be definitely a better way though,

**your question**

I cannot get the averages_table array to be defined outside of my function, so I cannot pass it through another.

**Answer**

The  array `averages_table` itself is created inside the function `Section1_5_airportAverages`, you just need to return it from the function to access it else where.

**Two things you need to correct**

1. `return statement` from within the `last elif condition`.
   This will return `averages_table` array if and only if that particular condition is True.

*Correction:* write a return statement outside of the for loop (a specific if statement is executed according to the condition, you don't need to return from the individual if statements)

2. Not sure why you are using a `while=True` conditon.

This will make your code run indefinitely(infinite loop)

*Correction:* please remove the `while=True` condition. I think the you only need to iterate over the whole code for 11 times( one year time frame), then the condition should be,

```
while count <= 11
```

I would suggest using ***pandas dataframe*** for your assignment which simplify things and is  a lot easier to implement.